# Laravel PHPUnit auto chose default connection

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to writing testing in Laravel with `phpunit`. However, when I run testing by `php artisan test`, laravel auto write and refresh on my main database. I've tried to create another database and set `phpunit` run with it but it doesn't work.

This is my `phpunit.xml` config:

```php
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="local"/>
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value="main_testing"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
```

The `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=main
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_TEST_CONNECTION=testing
DB_TEST_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_TEST_PORT=3306
DB_TEST_DATABASE=main_testing
DB_TEST_USERNAME=root
DB_TEST_PASSWORD=
```

Config `connections` in `config/database.php`:

```php
'testing' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_TEST_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_TEST_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_TEST_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_TEST_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_TEST_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_TEST_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

I've add some code to test in `Feature\ExampleTest.php`:

```php
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $admin = \App\Models\Admin::factory(10)->create();
        $response = $this->get('/');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

When I run `php artisan test`, I want records created in `main_testing` database but it keeps creating in `main` database.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Try putting all your testing related environment variables in `.env.testing`

Comment: @Donkarnash, it doesn't work. It still reset all data in ```main``` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have figured out reason why it don't work. It's because I ran `php artisan config:cache` instead of `php artisan config:clear`. If I run `config:cache`, laravel will clear all cached configuration and cached it again. Thus, all configuration in `phpunit.xml` is ignored and testing will run with `main` database.

I also find [a simple solution](https://hackernoon.com/how-i-destroyed-the-staging-database-b435f98569ab) to prevent database from deleted while test. Just add some configuration checks in `CreatesApplication` trait to make sure you are not using develop database for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and i find that config in phpunit.xml can fix.
Let give it a try.

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
```